# Suppose H is a subgroup of Q, what properties do I use for this question?

Tags: group-theory

Assuming that Q is a group under addition:

[image: question]

Comment: the function takes elements from Q to a subset of Q, so x is an element of Q

Comment: Did not see that $H$ was a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Each element of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be written in the form $\frac pq$, for some integers $p$ and $q>0$ where $(p,q) = 1$. Now we have:

$$\phi(p) = \phi(1 + 1 + \cdots + 1) = \phi(1) + \cdots + \phi(1) = p\phi(1); \quad p \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Also:

$$\phi(p) = \phi\left(\frac pq + \cdots + \frac pq\right) = \phi\left(\frac pq\right) + \cdots + \phi\left(\frac pq\right) = q\phi\left(\frac pq\right)$$

Hence: $$p\phi(1) = q\phi\left(\frac pq\right) \implies \phi\left(\frac pq\right) = \frac pq \phi(1) \implies \phi(x) = x \phi(1)$$